# How to compare 8 bits of input port

Tags: verilog

I am looking for the first 8 bits of an input port which is of 11 bits. How can we do it in verilog?  I am trying the following code. But it doesnot work.

```
     input [0:10]inputport1;
     if(inputport1==11'b11010101xxx) begin
     $display ("some value");
     end
```

or

```
     input [0:10]inputport1;
     if(inputport1[0:8]==9'b11010101) begin
     $display ("some value");
     end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ports should be (are typically) defined MSB to LSB.

```
input [11:0] x,
...
if (x[7:0] == 8'b0000_1111) begin
```

Comment: I am using some dont care conditions also, so === operator is important, which i understood above. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your question does not mention do not care, it says first 8 bits. Your having to use do not care because your bus is the wrong way around. This may start to cause you trouble later if you have to integrate other peoples work. It may cause linting errors and synthesis issues.

Comment: That means i need to place my bus with [7:0] arrangement

Comment: Yes, that would be the industry standard, and the recommendation in the [LRM (Language reference Manual)](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Comment: Thanks and appreciated the reference !

Comment: @NileshAgrawal No problem, hope you have fun with verilog.